# Calculating a (combined) variance of two samples with unequal variances

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance

Before I state my question, I would like to point out that I do not have a mathematics/statistics background, so please excuse my lack of rigor in the terminology I use.

I have two datasets of unequal size and unequal variance. I think they are independent samples: they events are disjoint, i.e. the events from one dataset are not contained in the other and vice versa. I know both the datasets' means, standard deviations, and variances. How do I calculate the standard deviation/ variance of the combined set of data? I have come across formulae for [pooled variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance), but that formula assumes the variance of the two samples to be equal, which is not the case in my situation/problem. Can I use [combined variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/557469/difference-between-pooled-variance-and-combined-variance) in my problem?

I would also be grateful if you could provide an academic reference to the same.

Comment: Because the variances are unequal, how are you hoping to use or interpret this "combined" variance?

Comment: @whuber I want to be able to get a rough value of the standard deviation if I were to "combine" the two datasets. I think what I mean by "combine" here is to just literally combine the values of the two datasets into one dataset. Does that answer your question?

Comment: (It seems like "combine" means "concatenate"). Why not simply combine them and then compute the variance of the combined dataset?

Comment: @JohnMadden thank you for the better term. I mainly do not want to do that because one of the dataset size is small with a large variance, and the other dataset size is large with a small variance. If I were to concatenate and calculate the variance, then the concatenated variance value tends to go towards the variance of the smaller dataset?! This introduces a bias I don't want. I wanted to check if there is a formal prescription in statistics to "combine" variances of two datasets which considers the dataset size. Also, I want to add that the means of the two datasets are different.

Comment: Your first comment stated " I want to be able to get a rough value of the standard deviation if I were to "combine" the two datasets." But now it does not sound like this is what you want. Also, if "just literally combine the values of the two datasets into one dataset" is not concatenate, then can you help us understand what it is?

Comment: You have two different datasets.  Again, *what would a combined variance mean?*  Why is the difference in sizes important or meaningful?

Comment: I can try to explain my problem with an example: I have a quantity, let us say temperature, that I am measuring from two different methods (say 2 thermometers). I have temperature measurements from both thermometers so I know the errors [standard deviation of (true temp - predicted temp)] of both thermometers. I am less interested in the temperature measurement itself. Can I estimate the error of a new measurement if someone were to choose a thermometer by random to make the measurement?